# Ajax datatables with 2 variables + render in a column

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I have a Datatable plugin working with ajax to load the data. I want get a result in a column based on 2 conditionals. The below code is working good but with just one conditional. I'mnot sue how to add status_token to the equation. I want to add status_token variable the same as status is working.

I've tried `status, status_token` and  `{ data: {'status': status, 'status_token': status_token}, render: function(status){` but it's not working.

```
$('#tableEvent').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "{!! route('datatables.data') !!}",
    columns: [
{ data: 'status_token', name: 'status_token' },
{ data: 'status', //<-- how can I add another variable status_token?
    render: function(status){ //<-- same here status_token
        if(status == 'hello'){
            return 'aa';

        }else{
            if(status_token == 'bye'){
                return 'bb';

            }else{
                return 'cc';
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

As per Rohit.007 suggestion I tried this code

```
{ data: {'status': 'status', 'status_token': 'status_token'},
    render: function(status, status_token){
```

But for some reason it's still not working, checking out the variable status_token I get "display" no idea what's that and why it's different from the first column which is returning the correct information.

New whole code:

```
$('#tableEvent').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "{!! route('datatables.data') !!}",
    columns: [

{ data: 'status_token', name: 'status_token' },

{ data: {'status': 'status', 'status_token': 'status_token'},
    render: function(status, status_token){
        if(status == 'hello'){
            return 'aa';

        }else{
            if(status_token == 'bye'){
                return 'bb';

            }else{
                return 'cc';
            } 
        } 
    }
}
],

responsive: true

});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and answer! I think you got what I wanted, but it's not working. On the other hand, I've updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: You must be passing it in function calls somewhere in you code like render('status','display')

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get you but still, are you looking for a similar thing?

```
{
  data: {
    'status': false,
    'status_token': 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf'
  },
  render: function(status){
    if(status=='hello'){
      return'aa';
    }else{
      if(status_token=='bye'){
        return'bb';
      }else{
        return'cc';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason it's giving me Uncaught ReferenceError: status_token is not defined

Comment: Do you have any variable with status_token? OR just try with quotes like  `{ data: {'status': 'status', 'status_token': 'status_token'}, render: function(status){`

Comment: either way I think it has to be render: function(status, **status_token**){ right?

Comment: Yes you can send it as parameter

Comment: question updated. but this is weird, the status_token variable on the first column it's working perfectly fine but on the second if I check it's returning me "display" what's display??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171352/discussion-between-tronne-and-rohit-007).

Comment: Can you vote-up and accept the answer if it helped you in any manner.

Answer (score 0):

Add another parameter in your `render` function. Then using it get the value of `status_token` field.

```
render: function(status, type, row){
        if(status == 'hello'){
            return 'aa';

        }else{
            if(row.status_token == 'bye'){
                return 'bb';

            }else{
                return 'cc';
            } 
        } 
    }
```

**Updated whole code:**

```
$('#tableEvent').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: "{!! route('datatables.data') !!}",
  columns: [{ data: 'status_token', name: "status_token" },
    { data: 'status': 'status', name: 'status',
      render: function(status, type, row) {
        if (status == 'hello') {
          return 'aa';

        } else {
          if (row.status_token == 'bye') {
            return 'bb';

          } else {
            return 'cc';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  responsive: true
});
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#tableEvent').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: "{!! route('datatables.data') !!}",
  columns: [

    {
      data: 'status_token',
      name: 'status_token'
    },

    {
      data: {
        'status': 'status',
        'status_token': 'status_token'
      },
      render: function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'hello') {
          return 'aa';

        } else {
          if (data.status_token == 'bye') {
            return 'bb';

          } else {
            return 'cc';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],

  responsive: true

});
```

It works for me.